# The Program exits if I start it can you help me?

Tags: python, mouse, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import mouse
import threading


def clicker():
    while True:
        while mouse.is_pressed("left"):
            x = pyautogui.position()
            pyautogui.click(x)


clicker()"
```

I already installed pyautogui and threading and for "mouse" I did pip install mouse, but idk  if this is right so pls help.

Comment: Please update your question with evidence of a crash. Did you mean that there is an error traceback?

Comment: What error message do you get? *Crashes* is not enoughto go on.

Comment: The program crashes without any error

Comment: But how do you know it crashes and not just exit with no error?

Comment: It exits without an error. But I dont want it to exit

Comment: It appears you have a double quotation mark next to your `clicker()` function when calling it. Try removing that and see if it works.

Comment: ah i see it. Thats not the error in the code I dont have this. It was a typing of me.

Comment: But theres a message if i run it in Pycharm theres a message:     import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Comment: @vpxnyy That's because you have to install the package in Pycharm as well. I don't think Pycharm reads all of your installed packages that you installed with pip.

Comment: thx, the error disappeared but if i want to start the program nothing happens... any solution?

Comment: If you get no errors, then try using some debugging strats like adding `print()` statements in some parts of your code to check what works and what doesn't work.

Comment: I did that. It didnt help aswell. I tried anouther program with the Module "mouse" and it also didnt work.

Comment: @vpxnyy What do you expect the output to be? Is a window supposed to appear, or is it through the console?

Comment: There has to be a window. There was a Window when I tried it with the keyboard module.